# Blank Web Service Identity, SSRS, Configure Report Server

Tags: asp.net, configuration, reporting-services

I am currently setting up a Sql Server Reporting Services onto a Windows 2000 server with IIS5 and SQL Server 2005.
The only thing I cannot get to configure is the Web Service Identity, in that the ASP .NET Service Account is blank and is read only.

I have tried adding the ASP account (*machinename*\ASPNET) into rsreportserver.config in the  tag but have had no luck.
Is there a way to find out what the current ASP .NET Service Account is?

Thanks,

Davoink

Comment: Did you read this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189361%28SQL.90%29.aspx
Might help. For IIS5, It always runs under the ASP.NET process identity.

Comment: What a nightmare I had with this.  It all stemmed from someone deleting the SQL Server by mistake and trying to configure from scratch.  Ended up rolling back the server to the day before the deletion took place, tweaked a few permssions and it was away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a nightmare I had with this. It all stemmed from someone deleting the SQL Server by mistake and trying to configure from scratch. 
Ended up rolling back the server to the day before the deletion took place, tweaked a few permssions and it was up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem (blank web service identity).  Changing webserviceaccount in rsreportserver.config didn't do it for me.  What did work however, was to just create new virtual roots for both ReportManager and ReportServer.  Do this from the SSRS Configuration tool.  Click the New button and make new ones.  The web service identity tab should then automatically go green.

If you prefer the original virtual root names then delete them first (using IIS Manager) and repeat the above steps to create new ones (using original names).

I learned this tip from this post: http://www.developmentnow.com/g/115_2007_8_0_0_1008242/Web-Service-Identiy-is-red-in-report-configuration-tool.htm

-Krip